# Trying to get only cells with certain initials but giving me syntax error? SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin, dbeaver

So my assignment question is to "Get a list of all books withdrawn by people with the initials 'B.W.'. Show a column for the first name, last name, initials, and the title of the book". I am trying to join these 3 tables as it is the only way to get this information, but Im having a hard time only displaying names with initials B.W. I get a syntax error saying:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'JOIN withdrawals

When I remove my 'WHERE' statement (all of the second line), my syntax error goes away. How do I make this work?

Below is my code:

```
 SELECT first_name, last_name, title FROM members 
     WHERE first_name LIKE 'B%' AND last_name LIKE 'W%'
      JOIN withdrawals  
        ON members.member_id  = withdrawals.member_id 
         JOIN books 
             ON withdrawals.book_id = books.book_id
```

Comment: `WHERE` goes after `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

JOIN should always be placed just after FROM table-name. The below should work

*SELECT first_name, last_name, title FROM members
JOIN withdrawals

ON members.member_id  = withdrawals.member_id
JOIN books
ON withdrawals.book_id = books.book_id
WHERE first_name LIKE 'B%' AND last_name LIKE 'W%'*

Answer (score 0):

There is a flow you have to follow when writing your SQL statements

```
SELECT * FROM table
JOIN table2 ON 
WHERE
GROUP BY
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow everything in order which goes like:

```
SELECT - FROM - JOIN & ON - WHERE - GROUP BY - HAVING - ORDER BY
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you will need to create a column called Initials. In this case, you can use SUBSTR to get the first letter from you first_name and the first letter from last_name. Then, you will need to CONCAT them together to make it a column.

```
CONCAT(SUBSTR(first_name,1,1), '.', SUBSTR(last_name,1,1), '.') AS Initials
```

After that, you need to find out who have the initials with B.W. . You can use LIKE ('B.W.'). Since you have a specific answer, you do not need to use %.

```
HAVING Initials LIKE ('B.W.')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTR(m.first_name,1,1) , '.', SUBSTR(m.last_name,1,1) ) AS "Initials"
FROM - JOIN - ON
WHERE m.first_name LIKE "B%" AND m.last_name LIKE "W%" ;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).